# How to configure rewrite rule for nginx over already binded port

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, rack, thin

My application is found here:

http://my.app.com:3000/

My assets are found here:

http://my.app.com:3000/dev-assets

My application references assets here:

http://my.app.com:3000/assets

I'm using a local rails server `thin` which is already taking port 3000. Is it possible to use nginx to rewrite `/assets/(.*?)$` to `/dev-assets/$1` under the same port, or am I approaching this completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In short, you need to change the port *thin* is listening right now. For example, it can be port 9000. Next, you create nginx config for my.app.com; specify port 3000. Then, all serve all requests to `/assets` into folder `dev-assets` on your filesystem (see `root` derective).

All other requests get passed (*proxied*) to `localhost:9000`.

Here is the sample nginx config illustrating mongrel integration (it doesn't matter which application server is listening the port): http://brainspl.at/nginx.conf.txt

Be sure to check out *thin* usage manual: http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/usage/